# Curl in PHP Via Get Request

Tags: php, curl

I am using Curl . i want to access url via Curl. When i direct Access url, it is working fine.  but via curl it doesnot display anything. 
here is my code

```
$baseurl="﻿https://www.addressfinder.co.nz/api/address?q=184+willis+st%2C+te+aro%2C+wellington+6011&key=9QTP8F3CHXEVU7WGYA6J&secret=KQLTAXY46M39RGHBFC8W&format=json";
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$res=curl_exec($ch);
echo $res;
```

it doesn't display nothing. Can anybody tell me how to do this. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure CURL is setup to access via SSL on your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works without SSL (`http` not `https`)

```
$baseurl="http://www.addressfinder.co.nz/api/address?q=184+willis+st%2C+te+aro%2C+wellington+6011&key=9QTP8F3CHXEVU7WGYA6J&secret=KQLTAXY46M39RGHBFC8W&format=json";
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$res=curl_exec($ch);
echo $res;
```

[This fix](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/) also appears to work:

```
$baseurl="https://www.addressfinder.co.nz/api/address?q=184+willis+st%2C+te+aro%2C+wellington+6011&key=9QTP8F3CHXEVU7WGYA6J&secret=KQLTAXY46M39RGHBFC8W&format=json";
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $baseurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

/* Turn off SSL verify peer */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$res=curl_exec($ch);
echo $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
$baseurl="https://www.addressfinder.co.nz/api/address?q=184+willis+st%2C+te+aro%2C+wellington+6011&key=9QTP8F3CHXEVU7WGYA6J&secret=KQLTAXY46M39RGHBFC8W&format=json";
$locate = json_decode(file_get_contents($baseurl),true);

$address=$locate['completions']['0']['a'];
echo $address;
?>
```

This will give you the result you want and you can access all data using array methods.